# Is $K$, a reduced finite $k$-algebra, whose spectrum $\operatorname{Spec}K$ is connected, a field?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In proof of

> For a reduced connected proper $k$-scheme $X$, $\mathscr{O}_X(X)$ is a field of finite degree over $k$.

I face the following lemma

> Is $K$, a reduced finite $k$-algebra, whose spectrum $\operatorname{Spec}K$ is connected, a field?

By a proposition I've shown, I have $\mathscr{O}_X(X)$ is a reduced finite $k$-algebra, and $\operatorname{Spec}\mathscr{O}_X(X)$ is connected.

So it remains to show the lemma.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A finite $k$-algebra $K$ is artinian, hence the spectrum consists of finitely many maximal ideals (= closed points). Thus the topology is discrete. A connected discrete space is a singleton, i.e. $K$ has only one maximal ideal, which is also the nil radical. But the nil radical is zero by assumption, i.e. $K$ is a field.

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't notice that elementary proposition. I still need to study more.